# Spring-Data/MongoDB/QueryDSL Searching nested _id of ObjectId type

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

When an document from a collection is nested inside a document of another collection, it's pretty standard to make a copy of the nested document verbatim instead of creating another type of document just for the sake of nesting. Ex:

```
category {"_id": ObjectId("c1"), "name": "Category 1"}
question {"_id": ObjectId("q1"), category: {"_id": ObjectId("c1"), "name": "Category 1"}}
```

When using queryDSL as follows:

```
question.category.id = "c1"
```

queryDSL generates a query like this:

```
"question.category._id":"c1"
```

where I expect:

```
"question.category._id":ObjectId("c1")
```

This works for top level documents, not for nested. I think this is a valid case and Spring should do the same translations it does for top level search. Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

QueryDSL will not convert String to ObjecetId on the fly since it is not aware of Spring Data annotations like `@Id` or `@Field(targetType = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)`. Therefore, it will look only at Java type of your field. I found this workaround to keep String Id but been able to compare with ObjectId. Taking your code as a reference I can give you this snippet:

```
Path<ObjectId> categoryIdPath = Expressions
                        .path(ObjectId.class, qQuestion.category.id.getMetadata());

Predicate predicate = Expressions.predicate(Ops.EQ, categoryIdPath,
                        Expressions.constant(new ObjectId("c1"))));
```